# Widget position is distorted when changing screen orientation

Tags: python, kivy

I had built an apk using buildozer 0.34 and kivy 1.10.0 and in my buildozer.spec, I had set the orientation as:

```
orientation = all
```

I opened my app in portrait and it looked like this:

[image]

However, when I change turn/rotated my phone in a landscape position, it looked like this:

[image]

Also when I ran my app in landscape position, it works normally but when rotated in a portrait position, it distorts the position of the widget.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text= "Hello World")

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: What kind of layout are you using to position the widget? Please show your code so we can help.

Comment: @George Bou, I didn't use any layout. I have attached the code at the bottom. It's just a simple button with a "Hello World" text.